# ffmpeg only converting 41.25% of my images to video

Tags: javascript, node.js, ffmpeg, fluent-ffmpeg

I"m using ffmpeg to covnert a list of images to a timelapse video. When i run the command from the commandline its works beautifully.

```
ffmpeg -r 3 -i /var/folders/qj/n910kwdj4gvbmy_z2ffc5lcc0000gp/T/tmp-22129yvIsrbso4TEu/image%03d.jpg -s hd1080 -vcodec libx264 timelapse.mp4
```

The issue occurs when i use nodejs library fluent-ffmpeg.

```
app.get('/api/get', function (req, res) {// return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    ffmpeg('/var/folders/qj/n910kwdj4gvbmy_z2ffc5lcc0000gp/T/tmp-22129yvIsrbso4TEu/image%03d.jpg')
      .noAudio()
      .inputOption('-r 3')
      .outputOptions([
        '-r', '3',
        '-s', 'hd1080'
      ]).  
      .videoCodec('libx264')
      .on('progress', (progress) => {
        console.log('Processing: ' + progress.percent + '% done');
      })
      .on('error', (err) => {
        console.error('Error during processing', err);
        // reject(err)
      })
      .on('end', () => {
        console.log('Processing finished !');
        // resolve()
      })
      .save('test.mp4', {end: true});
    }
    res.send(`I received your GET request.`);
});
```

**EDIT: Now gives me a processed video at Processing: 207.49999999999997% done
Processing finished ! but doesn't produce a video**

And my images are named as so image1.jpg, image2.jpg, image3.jpg, etc

Its very confusing when i run the command directly in my cli.

Anyone run into this issue before or am i just using the library wrong?

Comment: `-r 3` should be an input option.

Comment: Thats now changed it to 

`Processing: 207.49999999999997% done
Processing finished !`

Comment: Share full ffmpeg log. Add -report to the ffmpeg cmd  to generate log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact you're converting only 41.25% might be caused by the type of pattern used here **image%d.jpg**. When using `ffmpeg -r 3 -i /var/folders/qj/n910kwdj4gvbmy_z2ffc5lcc0000gp/T/tmp-22129yvIsrbso4TEu/image%d.jpg -s hd1080 -vcodec libx264 timelapse.mp4` You must have a sequence of images like:

- image-1.png
- image-2.png
- image-3.png
- image-4.png

In having image-9.png after image-4.png. The video ends up at image-4.png. So you have 2 choices here. Make sure you have the correct number sequence in all filenames or use a glob pattern.

If you're looking for a glob pattern:

```
app.get('/api/get', function (req, res) {// return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    ffmpeg('/var/folders/qj/n910kwdj4gvbmy_z2ffc5lcc0000gp/T/tmp-22129yvIsrbso4TEu/image*.jpg')
      .noAudio()
      .outputOptions([
        '-r', '3',
        '-s', 'hd1080'
      ]).  
      .videoCodec('libx264')
      .on('progress', (progress) => {
        console.log('Processing: ' + progress.percent + '% done');
      })
      .on('error', (err) => {
        console.error('Error during processing', err);
        // reject(err)
      })
      .on('end', () => {
        console.log('Processing finished !');
        // resolve()
      })
      .save('test.mp4', {end: true});
    }
    res.send(`I received your GET request.`);
});
```

Reference here: http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Slideshow#Globpattern

Comment: Thanks for for you input. I now use the %03d numbering sequence which helps and changed the `-r 3` to inputOptions as suggested above by Gyan. But now it seems to give me this...

`Processing: 207.49999999999997% done
Processing finished !`

Some pogress but not quite what i'm after lol